# Incorrect Currency Format for DKK

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

DKK currency format is not displaying correct formatting for the Krone. Correct format is kr40.000,00 but it displays kr40,000.00 as we've for US.

This is the js fiddle link [JS Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/nqf0ye00/102/)  I've edited an example. Actually I'm using this code `$filter('currency')(amount, currency.symbol || (currencyCode + ' '), fractionSize)` Which is showing DKK in wrong format.
Please confirm that is it a bug or I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: You're using the Angular [`currency` filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency) which takes into account the configured [i18n](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n) settings which you have not changed from the default.

Comment: If I provide the currency code in the filter, shouldn't it format it to the that provided code?.

Comment: You aren't providing the code though, just a currency symbol. You didn't read the i18n guide, did you?

Comment: Now I see it. I need to refer the locale which I need to transform. Thanks Phil for ur link. Now I need to solve my actual problem. I need to change currency format with respect to location. However my application running the eng version. but my currency format should be according to the location which I selected from dropdown. Can u help in this regard?

Comment: IMO, i18n in Angular is just crap but this might help a little ~ http://lgalfaso.github.io/angular-dynamic-locale/. Good luck